# Как подружить kivy +figma?

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Доброго времени суток))) Есть ли возможности использовать figma + kivy? Знаю что с помощью tkinter можно загрузить с помощью url и токена, что можно сделать если нужно сделать дизайн для мобильного приложения на kivy?